# Como criar um "Principal" em uma aplicação que consome um serviço REST que possui todas as entidades do sistema?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

Estou com o seguinte aplicação web criada inicialmente para e web usando o Spring Boot, Spring Security e Thymeleaf (autenticação e autorização).

Fiz um serviço REST e separei o *front-end* em outra aplicação que consome os serviços através do `RestTemplate`. Toda aplicação está usando JWT e Spring Security para a autenticação e autorização. Fiz vários testes com o Postman e tudo está ok.

O problema é que não consigo montar o *login* na aplicação cliente por não saber como criar o Principal, pois ele esta na mesma aplicação e não em um servidor remoto.

- Como devo criar meu controller para o login especificamente?

  - Antes podia usar o UserDetail e o UserDetailService e era bem simples
  - Mas agora vou precisar credenciais em todas as requisições
- Como posso capturar o usuário logado na aplicação cliente para poder lidar com suas permissões de acesso as paginas e seus conteúdos que já estão configurados com o Thymeleleaf e Spring Security?
- Onde encontrar um exemplo de uma aplicação Spring Boot consumindo uma API REST fazendo o login para ter acesso aos demais recursos?

No projeto cliente estou fazendo assim para obter o token:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String token = fazerLogin();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/usuario/perfil/155";
        Map<String, String> param2 = new HashMap();
        param2.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> usuarioLogado;
        usuarioLogado = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        System.out.println("Usuario Logado =>" + usuarioLogado);
    }

    private String fazerLogin() throws RestClientException {
        Map<String, String> param = new HashMap();
        param.put("email", "lucival@gmail.com");
        param.put("senha", "123");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/login";
        ResponseEntity<String> response;
        response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, param, String.class);
        String leitura = response.toString().substring(21, 195);
        System.out.println("Leitura  =>" + leitura);
        String token = leitura.substring(7, 174);
        System.out.println("Token  =>" + token);
        return token;
    }
}
```

Li esse [artigo](https://www.baeldung.com/authentication-against-a-third-party-service) interessante, porém não tem a aplicação toda, apenas pequenos trechos.

Answer (score -1):

Não compreendi bem sobre qual aplicação você usara no front, esse front é o que?

Pagina web, aplicativo?

Vou supor que você tem uma aplicação front-end web (HTML, CSS e Javascript), um cliente do seu serviço principal que esta em Java e o serviço Java que você usa Spring Security, blz, se eu estiver errado menciona ai com mais detalhes pra mim tentar ajudar.

## Login

Após efetuado o login, você recebera o JWT.

No payload do JWT, você pode armazenar algumas informações que ira precisar do usuário logado.

**Exemplo:**

```js
  {
    "aud": [
    "restservice"
    ],
    "updatePassword": false,
    "user_name": "user@email.com",
    "scope": [
      "all"
    ],
    "name": "Andre",
    "id": "{id}",
    "exp": 1622294739,
    "authorities": [
      "ROLE_CRIAR_USUARIOS",
      "ROLE_EDITAR_USUARIOS",
      "ROLE_INATIVAR_USUARIOS",
      "ROLE_VISUALIZAR_USUARIOS"
    ],
    "jti": "22b37833-238d-46c0-9429-36cdb8c39341",
    "client_id": "client"
  }
```

### Parse JWT to Payload

Caso deseja fazer o parse do payload e ler os dados é só implementar a seguinte função:

```js
 sys.parseJwt = function (token) {
    var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function (c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));

    return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
};
```

e chamar depois usando

```js
  var payload = sys.parseJwt(jwt);
```

### Salvar e usar em requisições posteriores

Para isso mude um pouco a estrutura do login no back-end, criando um método que faz o login e caso tenha sucesso retorne o JWT.

No front, após o retorno do JWT salve ele no local Storage

```js
 sessionStorage.setItem('token', res.jwt);
```

e nas requisições posteriores, adicione no header.

```js
const jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);
```

Answer (score -1):

Você deve criar uma classe de configuração para deixar algumas rotas publicas na sua aplicação!

vou deixar abaixo um exemplo de como fazer isso, adapte-a a sua versão do spring!

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/private/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_" + "ADMINISTRATOR")
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();


 }
}
```

nesse exemplo ele vai exigir o token quando vc bater em alguma rota do tipo:
localhost:8080/private/

e vai deixar livre as rotas:
localhost:8080/public/

e tudo que vier a frente dessas urls